# Two Instances of Sql Server (2005 and 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, configuration, instance

I installed Visual Studio 2008 Professional in my machine and It had installed SQL Server Express 2005 database in machine, and I use it very fine! I installed SQL Managment Studio and works great.

So, in this week I Installed Visual Studio 2010 Pro in machine and the setup installed the SQL Server express 2008 and it overwrite the instance of my SQL Server Express 2005.

All right, Now, I'd like to know how can I have two instances of the SQL Server Express in my Machine, Express 2005 and Express 2008. I can not access the 2005 , only 2008 :( and my projects uses 2005.. Somebody Help me!

thanks
Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Uninstall 2008
2. Install 2005 as a named instance (not default).  Install all 2005 service packs
3. Install 2008 as the default instance.  Install all 2008 service packs

Note that you can make 2005 the default if you prefer.  Unfortunately, you must uninstall 2008 to get side-by-side to work.

Comment: Thanks man! I appreciate, I unistall the sql server 2008, e install with a named instance... my default is 2005. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can installed a named instance

you access it with ComputerName\Instancename

so on my laptop you can see I have 2 instances, the sql2008r2 is the named instance

[image]